# Implement an inherited function - VB.net

Tags: vb.net, winforms, interface

I've a form class, named `EditCellForm` that should implement the interface `ICoordsRequester`.

This interface requires the `Focus()` method to be implemented.

As long it's a form, my class already implements the `Focus()` method but the compiler cannot see it because it's in the `Windows.Forms.Form` superclass.

Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a new `Focus` method using the `Shadows` keywords to implement the interface:

```
Class EditCellForm 
    Inherits Form
    Implements ICoordsRequester

    Shadows Sub Focus Implements ICoordsRequester.Focus
        Mybase.Focus
    End Sub

End Class
```

or rename your method

```
Class EditCellForm 
    Inherits Form
    Implements ICoordsRequester

    Sub NewFocus Implements ICoordsRequester.Focus
        Focus()
    End Sub

End Class
```

Answer (score 2):

You can implement the method as usual, but just call it something different.  Then in the method, just call the Focus event of the base class.  If all it does is the same thing, I'd just make it private so that it's only accessible via the interface.

```
Public Class EditCellForm
    Implements ICoordsRequester 

    Private Sub ICoordsRequester_Focus() Implements ICoordsRequester.Focus
        Me.Focus()
    End Sub
End Class
```